# How does combining data affect the resulting file entropy?

Tags: entropy

If i add a password which has (X) bits of entropy as a tag to a picture which has (Y) bits of entropy, will the resulting image have an entropy equal to (X + Y) ?

How many bits of entropy i get if i save a password which has (A) bits of entropy inside an empty text file, then i use "copy /b" command to combine the text file with a picture which has (B) bits of entropy?

Comment: what is "copy /b"?

Comment: @kodlu **copy** is a Windows command that copies files. **/b** is an argument to treat files as binary. If we use **copy /b file1** **+** **file2 file3** , file3 will look exactly like a twin of file1. But actually it has all the data of file2 included at the end. More details [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy)

Comment: thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not necessarily. It depends on how much the data $Y$ is related to the data $X$. The technical term is [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) and is written $I(X,Y)$ and can be defined as the difference between the combined entropy and the sum of the entropy of the components:
$$I(X,Y)=H(X)+H(Y)-H(X,Y).$$

For example, if the data $Y$ is generated independently of data $X$ (e.g. you generate a tag from a random noise source and append this to an image), then the mutual information is 0 and the entropy is additive.

If the data $Y$ is a deterministic function of $X$ (e.g. you tag the image with a hash of meta-data about the image such as file size and date), then the mutual information is equal to $H(Y)$ and the combined file has no more entropy than $H(X)$.

If the data $Y$ depends loosely on $X$ (e.g. you tag the data with a word that the image inspires or with a search term that produces the image as an option on Google images), then the mutual information is somewhere in-between.

For a toy example, suppose I have image files that are 2x2 grids of black and white pixels and each image is equiprobable. Thus there are 16 possible files and the entropy of a file is 4-bits. I'll tag each file with a bit which $\frac34$ of the times 0 and $\frac14$ of the time is 1, so that the tags in isolation have roughly 0.811-bits of entropy.

Now, in case a) I shall generate tags by rolling a fair four-sided die, tagging with 1 if I roll a four and 0 otherwise. It should be clear that data and tag are independent and all possible combinations of data and tag are possible and the entropy of the image-tag pair is roughly 4.811-bits.

In case b) I shall tag with 1 if the top two pixels are the same colour AND the the bottom two pixels are the same colour; I shall tag with 0 otherwise. Note that $\frac14$ of images will be tagged with 1. In this case there are only 16 possible image-tag pairs and the entropy of image-tag pairs is 4-bits.

In case c) I tag images with an number of black pixels with a 0; for other images I shall flip a fair coin and tag 0 if the coin is heads and 1 if it is tails. Again note that $\frac14$ of tags are 1. There are now 24 possible image-tag pairs and the entropy of image tag-pairs is 4.5-bits.

In case a) the mutual information is 0; in case b) is is roughly 0.811 bits and in case c) it is roughly 0.311-bits.

Comment: @PaulUszak I've very carefully not assumed anything about the independence of password and image. Having seen a number of statistical crimes committed based on an unwarranted assumption of independence, I tend to be very wary of this. If you can point to the bit in the question where it's made absolutely clear that the data are independent, I can do away with much of the answer.

Comment: @PaulUszak It's difficult to quantify, but I do know of cases where cryptanalytic advantage has been gained by deducing how targets came up with passwords. In my own experience, at least one Internet banking website asked me to come up with a word/phrase that I would mnemonically associate with an image.

Comment: Daniel, your formula is wrong/inappropriate. I think that you've confused entropies X and Y with the X and Y variables in your formula. I knew there was something wrong, but I couldn't put my finger on it until now. There is no mutual information shared between two entropies, which is what the question is about. oqdn's X and Y are not variables, they are quantities of entropy. There is no X data given Y data. And entropy is simply additive.

Answer (score 2):

> If i add a password which has (X) b...

Yes if you treat the resultant thingie as a single entity. Entropy is additive.

Although, in reality you will find it extremely difficult to measure/estimate the entropy of a password (not a key), and of an image that looks like anything real. Semantics, grammar and linguistics introduce correlations into words like passwords which make accurate entropy measurement virtually impossible. Similar graphic rules apply to pictures.

I'm assuming that your tag is textual meta-data stored within the image file like `exif`.

> How many bits of entropy i get if...

A + B. A binary concatenation is equivalent to inserting meta-data. It's just that the text file will be appended to the image, rather than within it. Similar entropy measurement problems still apply as before.

Comment: I've upvoted this answer as it adds meaningful information, but the most interesting thing in [this other answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/101067/1172). You've (correctly) indicated that if X and Y are entropy indications then X and Y **should** be independent by definition. However, I am not convinced that the anybody that has this question is aware of that.